# how can i read 3500 rows from a csv file using pandas?

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, large-data

`pd.read_csv(...)`

1. I try by this but it's just read 1520rows. But the main CSV file has 35000 rows.

Comment: Title and body of question are inconsistent - is it a 3500-row CSV file or a 35000-row CSV-file?

Comment: Can you give context and explain what your data looks like? Where did you see that the .csv file has 35000 rows and ntot 1520?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the “nrows” field at the read_csv() function:

```
Import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(“some.csv”,nrows=3500)
```

Also you can find more information at this link [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: This error is shown:
C:\Users\prono\PycharmProjects\EducationaldataofBD\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/prono/PycharmProjects/EducationaldataofBD/venv/demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1151, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1281, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype

Comment: File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1297, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1520, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 26: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/prono/PycharmProjects/EducationaldataofBD/venv/demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    country = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\prono\\PycharmProjects\\EducationaldataofBD\\venv\\abc.csv', nrows=35000)

Comment: You need to check the encoding of your csv file. There are different types [see py doc][1].

Next, you can change the encoding option of your read_csv().
Ie:

    df= pd.read_csv(“some.csv”, encoding=“utf-8”, nrows=3500)

 [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings